# Forge API- Two Leg token is fetching multiple Top folders which are not visible

Tags: autodesk-forge, two-legged

I am using Two-leg token authentication to fetch top project folders Id under a given hubId and project Id.
The response is giving multiple folders which are not even visible in BIM360 UI (response has hidden key, which irrespective of true or false not visible). Generally, there are two folders i.e. 'Plans' & 'Project Files'. If I use three-leg token authentication, then I am getting the correct result with 2 folders.
Please suggest any reason which is causing multiple folder responses in return using Two-leg token authentication.

Comment: Actually the 3 legged context returns Plans, Project Files, Recycle Bin and Shop Drawings for Project Admins. The BIM 360 Docs UI will display only the ones assigned to the user with the visibility set to True. What are the user's permissions?

Comment: @JaimeRosales -  The user is having 'Project Admin' permission. I want only the 'Project Files' and 'Plans' folder to be retrieved with two leg token. Passing additional header of 'x-user-id' as key and uid of my user as value is not fetching any folder.